# Calling convention Error!! (The value of ESP was not properly saved across a function call)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, dll, calling-convention

I am new to creating  DLL libraries in c++ here is my code

```
//header.h
class A
{
  virtual int  funct()=0;  //Pure virtual function 
};
```

Project B(which generates a DLL on compilation)

```
#include "header.h"
#define B_DLL __declspec( dllexport )
class B_DLL B: public A
{
  //Definitions of the 3 pure virtual functions are here
  int funct() 
  {
    //definition go here
  }

};
```

Now  I create an instance of class A and calling **funct()** then I am getting error

```
Run-Time Check Failure #0 - The value of ESP was not properly saved across a
function call.  This is usually a result of calling a function declared with
one calling convention with a function pointer declared with a different calling
convention.
```

How this can be resolved using Calling conventions **_cdecl** or **_stdcall**.I searched this a lot But couldn't find exactly how this error can be resolved Please help me in resolving this

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Can you show the code that instantiates the object that implements `A`'s abstract interface?

Answer (score 0):

`A` is a purely abstract class (interface), you can not initialize an abstract class nor use its methods directly. You should initialize its derivative`B_DLL` instead.